# Error in SQL when using alias in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 tables

```
doctor(doc_name.doc_id.dept_code,consult_fee)
dept(dept_name,dept_code)
patient(consult_fee,patient-name,doc_id)
```

The query is displaying the details of all doctors whose number of consultations is less than that of all doctors in 'Gynaecology' department.

I am writing the query

```
select count(b.consult_id) as top 
from info_faculty.wc_doctor a join info_faculty.wc_patient b on a.doc_id=b.doc_id 
where top <any (select count(b.consult_id) 
                 from info_faculty.wc_patient group by a.doc_id ) 
group by a.doc_id;
```

But it is giving me the error

> error---"TOP": invalid identifier

Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to use the `HAVING` clause in place of the `WHERE` clause for the aggregate functions

Comment: i have used where for any clause...it is mandatory

Comment: error---"TOP": invalid identifier

Comment: I insist you learn about the difference between the WHERE and HAVING. Google it

Comment: i have used where clause with 'any'...........i cannot use having with 'any'.It works with where only.

Comment: i have not used where with group by.

Comment: `top` is reserved, use some other name

Comment: no top is not reserved..............elsewise i have used other names also but the error is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(b.consult_id) as top 
from info_faculty.wc_doctor a join info_faculty.wc_patient b on a.doc_id=b.doc_id 
where count(b.consult_id) <any (select count(b.consult_id) 
                 from info_faculty.wc_patient group by a.doc_id ) 
group by a.doc_id;
```

I don't where that any is coming from but you cannot use the alias you are making in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: you need to use having here and need to select doctor.* and group with that according to op question

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work.  Note that you don't include consult_id in your list of fields for patient.

```
SELECT  a.doc_id, a.doc_name, a.dept_code, a.consult_fee, count(c.consult_id) 
FROM    test.doctor a,
        test.dept b,
        test.patient c
WHERE   a.doc_id = c.doc_id
AND a.dept_code = b.dept_code
AND b.dept_name != 'Gynaecology' #assuming you want to exclude doctors in Gynaecology dept
group by a.doc_id, a.doc_name, a.dept_code, a.consult_fee
Having count(c.consult_id) <   (SELECT count(b.consult_id) 
                    FROM test.dept a, test.patient b, test.doctor c 
                    WHERE a.dept_name = 'Gynaecology'
                    AND a.dept_code = c.dept_code 
                    AND c.doc_id = b.doc_id)
```